# Regex match if there is only one match from a number of choices in a string

Tags: regex, pcre

Is there a pattern for finding if there is only one match from a number of options in a string?

Let's say we have the following list of potential matches:

```
`foo|bar|baz`
```

And we have the strings:

```
`Foo bar, Cambaz!` // shoud not match due to multiple findings
`My bar, good!` // shoud match for `bar`
`My friend, Cambaz!` // shoud match for baz
```

Case insensitive.

Comment: Please show your attempts

Comment: @anubhava Honestly, I have no idea! :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this PCRE regex:

```
^(?>.*?(foo|bar|baz)){2}.*(*SKIP)(*F)|(?1)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zz6cQn/2)

- `(*F)` or `(*FAIL)` verb behaves like a failing negative assertion and is a synonym for `(?!)`
- `(*SKIP)` defines a point beyond which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack when the subpattern fails later
- The idea of the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` trick is to consume characters that you want to avoid, and that must not be a part of the match result.
- `(?1)`: recurses the 1st subpattern

Comment: You are a genius! Number 2 should be x-1 I guess...

Comment: @SorinGFS: To avoid repetition use: `^(?>.*?(foo|bar|baz)){2}.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\g<1>`

Comment: Nice! Why don't you add it to the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
(?i)^(?:(?!foo|bar|baz).)*\K(?:foo|bar|baz)(?!.*(?:foo|bar|baz))
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/FvQbO7/2).

Match some text that does not match any of the alternatives up to the first match (`^(?:(?!foo|bar|baz).)*`), omit the matched text (`\K`), match the word from list (`(?:foo|bar|baz)`), and then check there is no word from the list later in the text (`(?!.*(?:foo|bar|baz))`).

`(?i)` - case insensitive.

**Shortened version with subroutines**:

```
(?i)^(?:(?!(foo|bar|baz)).)*\K\g<1>(?!.*\g<1>)
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/FvQbO7/3)

`\g<1>` stands for the `(foo|bar|baz)` pattern.

Comment: Your latest version is also beautiful, because we don't have to repeat the strings we are looking for. Unfortunately @anubhava was faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `(*COMMIT)` to abort further researches when the subpattern after (a lookahead here) fails:

```
(foo|bar|baz)(*COMMIT)(?!.*(?1))
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/6CGPbw/1)

Comment: Yes, very nice, the shortest until now, due to the way it works it is probably the fastest. Thank you!